# Help choosing authentication method

Tags: java, security, authentication, ldap, kerberos

I need to choose an authentication method for an application installed and integrated in customers environment. There are two types of environments - windows and linux/unix. Application is user based, no web stuff, pure Java. The requirement is to authenticate users which will use my application against customer provided user base. Meaning, customer installs my app, but uses his own users to grant or deny access to my app. Typical, right?

I have three options to consider and I need to pick up the one which would be a) the most flexible to cover most common modern environments and b) would take least effort while stay robust and standard.

**Option (1)** - Authenticate locally managing user credentials in some local storage, e.g. file. Customer would then add his users to my application and it will then check the passwords. Simple, clumsy but would work. Customers would have to punch every user they want to grant access to my app using some UI we will have to provide. Lots of work for me, headache to the customer.

**Option (2)** - Use LDAP authentication. Customers would tell my app where to look for users and I will walk their directory resolving names into user names and trying to bind with found password. This is better approach IMO, but more fragile because I will have to walk an unknown directory structure and who knows if this will be permitted everywhere. Would be harder to test since there are many LDAP implementation out there, last thing I want is drowning in this voodoo.

**Option(3)** - Use plain Kerberos authentication. Customers would tell my app what realm (domain) and which KDC (key distribution center) to use. In ideal world these two parameters would be all I need to set while customers could use their own administration tools to configure domain and kdc. My application would simply delegate user credentials to this third party (using JAAS or Spring security) and consider success when third party is happy with them.

I personally prefer #3, but not sure what surprises I might face. Would this cover windows and *nix systems entirely? Is there another option to consider?

Answer (score 0):

Go with LDAP. Access is very easy, and the only parameter you need is the LDAP Server (and ActiveDirectory is one). If the user exists and the password is correct, he will always be able to log into the LDAP server.

Comment: Actually it's not the only parameter.. as I count - I need to specify host and port of LDAP server, credentials to walk the directory, locations containing users and fields corresponding to user name and password. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just to compare with plain Kerberos authentication - it only requires host-port of KDC and realm. Active directory can authenticate with Kerberos, like most other LDAP servers... What benefit is there to use LDAP walkking?

Comment: Authentication is only one side of the medal. Authorization comes next, when you decide, what the user yue just authenticated is authorized to do. I would go with LDAP to fetch the group associations of the user which I would match to the groups of my own access control.